# If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all integers, and $b>c$, If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, then does $a\mid b-c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all integers, and $b>c$, If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, then does $a\mid b-c$?

I'm almost positive that this property is true, but I can't find a name or proof for it.

Comment: If $b=ma$ and $c=na$ then $b-c=(m-n)a$, so yes.

Comment: Since $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $b=am$ and $c=an$. Clearly $b-c=am-an=a(m-n)$, and $m-n$ is an integer, so $a\mid b-c$.

Comment: If $a|b$ and $a|c$, then not only does $a$ divide their difference, but it divides every linear combination of $b$ and $c$, i.e. $bu+cv$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a|b$ and $a|c$ then for some $m,n$, $b=ma$ and $c=na$, so $b-c=(m-n)a$, and we have $a|b-c$.

Note that there is no reason for the restriction $b>c$. It is perfectly okay to say, for example, $2|(-10)$, since $-10=(-5)2$. We also allow for things like $2|0$, since $0=(0)2$.

More generally, if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a$ divides any linear combination of $b$ and $c$. I'll leave you to show this; it is similar to the above proof.